# Javascript phone validation not working

Tags: javascript, php, materialize

I have this JavaScript code for validation for phone. But I have tried all possible things have got no success. And my datepicker validations also is not working.

Here is my code snippet

```
 <html>
    <head>
      <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
      <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
      <!--Import materialize.css-->
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>

        <!--fonts-->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baloo+Chettan" rel="stylesheet"> 
      <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>


        <style>
        .parallax img{
      display: inherit !important;
}
                    input#proceed{
cursor:pointer; /*forces the cursor to change to a hand when the button is hovered*/
padding:5px 25px; /*add some padding to the inside of the button*/
background:#35b128; /*the colour of the button*/
border:1px solid #33842a; /*required or the default border for the browser will appear*/
/*give the button curved corners, alter the size as required*/
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
/*give the button a drop shadow*/
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0, .75);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0, .75);
box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0, .75);
/*style the text*/
color:#f3f3f3;
font-size:1.1em;
}
/***NOW STYLE THE BUTTON'S HOVER AND FOCUS STATES***/
input#gobutton:hover, input#gobutton:focus{
background-color :#399630; /*make the background a little darker*/
/*reduce the drop shadow size to give a pushed button effect*/
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0, .75);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0, .75);
box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0, .75);
}

                    body{
       background:url("back.jpg");
       background-size: cover;       /* For flexibility */
                        font-family: 'Baloo Chettan', cursive;
       }


        </style>

    </head>

    <body>
                        <script>
function validateForm()
{
    var phone = document["form"]["phone"].value;
     var email = document["form"]["email"].value;
     var atpos = email.indexOf("@");
     var dotpos = email.lastIndexOf(".");
    var birthdate = document["form"]["birthdate"].value;
    var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;  

   if(first_name.value.match(letters) && last_name.value.match(letters) && state.value.match(letters) && city.value.match(letters) )  
     {  
      return true;  
     }  
   else  
     {  
     alert("Enter text");  
     return false;  
     }  

    if(birthdate.value == "")
    {
        alert("Please Enter the Expected date to join ");
        document.form.birthdate.focus();
        return false;
    }

    if(phone=="")
    {
        alert("please Enter the Contact Number");
        document.form.phone.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if(isNaN(phone))
    {
        alert("Enter the valid Mobile Number(Like : 5555555555)");
        document.form.phone.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if((phone.length != 10))
    {
        alert(" Your number is invalid");
        document.form.phone.select();
        return false;
    }


            //email


    if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=email.length) {
        alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
        return false;
    }
}

</script>

        <div class = "navbar-fixed">
      <nav class="white">
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <a href="index.html" class="brand-logo center"><image src = "logosample.png" width="170px" height="55px" style = "padding-top : 2px;"/></a>
      <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons" style = "color:indigo;">menu</i></a>
      <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down" >
        <li><a href="gallery.html" style = "color:indigo ;"><i class="material-icons right">supervisor_account</i>Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html" style = "color:indigo ;"><i class="material-icons right">phone</i>Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo" style = "color:white;">
           <li><a href="index.html" style = "color:indigo ;">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery.html" style = "color:indigo ;">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html" style = "color:indigo ;">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
            </div>
        <!--Parallex starts here-->

    <div class="parallax-container">
      <div class="parallax"><img src="images/.jpg"></div>
    </div>
        <!--<h1>Hello Materialize</h1>-->
    <section>
        <center>
        <h1>Enquiry Form</h1>
        </center>
            <div class="row container">
    <form class="col s12" action="iihtinsertc.php" method = "POST" name='form' onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <input id="first_name" type="text" name = "firstname" class="validate" required>
          <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
        </div>
    </div>

        <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <input id="last_name" type="text" name = "lastname" class="validate" required>
          <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
        </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <input id="email" type="email" name = "email" class="validate" required>
          <label for="email">Email</label>
        </div>
    </div>
            <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <input id="phone" type="text" name = "phone" class="validate" required>
          <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
        </div>
    </div>
            <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <input disabled value="Cloud" id="disabled" name = "android" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="disabled">Course</label>
        </div>
      </div>

            <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <input id="state" type="text" name = "state" class="validate" required>
          <label for="state">State</label>
        </div>
    </div>

            <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <input id="city" type="text" name = "city" class="validate" required>
          <label for="city">City</label>
        </div>
    </div>

                <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <input disabled value="Goa Center" id="disabled" type="text" name = "center" class="validate">
          <label for="disabled">Center</label>
        </div>
      </div>

        <div class="row">
         <div class="col s12">
          <label for="birthdate">Expected to Join</label>
          <input type="text" id="birthdate" name = "exptj" class="datepicker" required>
        </div>

        </div>

        <!--<div class = "row">
        <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" href = ""><i class="material-icons right">send</i>Submit</a>
        </div>-->

        <input id= "proceed" type="submit" value = "Submit" name = "submit"/>


    </form>
    </div>
        </section>

        <!--Footer -->


  <footer class="page-footer indigo">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col l6 s12">
          <h5 class="white-text">Company Bio</h5>
          <p class="grey-text text-lighten-4">We are Asia's No 1 hardware and software institute. With amazing infrastructure and trained IIHT Trainers we help our students acheive their goal. </p>
    </div>
        <div class="col l3 s12">
          <h5 class="white-text">Quick Links</h5>
          <ul>
            <li><a class="white-text" href="gallery.html"><i class="material-icons">arrow_right</i>Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a class="white-text" href="contact.html"><i class="material-icons">arrow_right</i>Contact Us</a></li>

          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col l3 s12">
          <h5 class="white-text">Connect</h5>
          <ul>
            <li><a class="white-text" href="http://www.facebook.com/iihtgoa"><i class="material-icons">thumb_up</i>Facebook</a></li>
            <li><a class="white-text" href="http://www.iiht.com"><i class="material-icons">language</i>Website</a></li>

          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
        </footer>

        <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>  
        <script src="js/init.js"></script>


                <script>

$('.datepicker').pickadate({
  min: new Date(2016,8,19),
  max: new Date(2016,10,27),
    format: 'dddd, dd mmm, yyyy',
  formatSubmit: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
  hiddenPrefix: 'prefix__',
  hiddenSuffix: '__suffix'

});
                    </script>
            <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
       $('.parallax').parallax();});</script>

    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Did you accidentally include a real phone number in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User pattern Attribute instead -

```html
<form id="form">
<input type="tel" pattern="[0-9]{10}">
  <input type="submit">
  </form>
```

Comment: But after i do tha i find that all my other validations have stopped working!!.. why is that?

Comment: @Sshank - Is your issue resolved or not?? Let me know which specific validation is not working.

Comment: i have used pattern for every input of mine!!.. and that made it worked. Thanks a lot for this solution!..Patterns worked!! Only problem waas wen i tried using pattrn and javascript it was conflicting and dint work!!

Answer (score 0):

use below parseInt

```
if(parseInt(phone) != phone)
{
alert("Enter the valid Mobile Number(Like : 9566137117)");
document.form.phone.focus();
return false;
}
```